# How do I get values from list of object based on selected value in Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

**Updated with a simple example in the end**

I have a list of objects that are rendered into a canvas. This objects holds another object that are an base class

```
public class FooBase()
{
}

public class Foo1 : FooBase()
{
}

public class Foo2 : FooBase()
{
   public ICollection<Bar> BarList() { get;set; }
}

public class Bar
{
   public BarIdentifier BarIdentifier {get; set;}
   public int Value1 {get; set;}
   public string Value2 {get; set; }
}

public class HolderClass()
{
   public FooBase FooClass() { get; set; }

   public int PosX {get;set;}
   public int PosY {get;set;}
}
```

In my Model I also have an selection of an active Bar class. This is set by using a dropdown. I also have a List of HolderClasses

```
public BarIdentifier SelectedBar {get;set;}

public List<ValveSystemOverviewGridContent> HolderList {get;set;}
```

In my markup/xaml I have this

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding HolderList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=XPos, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=YPos, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

and the datatemplates as this

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type entities:Foo1 }" >
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <Label Content="FooClass 1" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type entities:Foo2 }">
        <Border CornerRadius="4" Background="White" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource NormalBorderBrush}" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label Content="Foo Class 2" />

                <Label Content="{Binding ????" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type entities:HolderClass }">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  >
            <Label Content="This is Holder Class" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=FooClass}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

</UserControl.Resources>
```

What I would like to do in the FooBar2 datatemplate is to get one of the items in BarList that matches to the SelectedBar. This would I do normally by using

```
BarList.First(b => b.BarIdentifier.Id == modelView.SelectedBar.Id);
```

Is there any way to accomplish this filter/selection in my data template and display the Value1 and Value2 of Bar in effective way?

If I change the dropdown in main view I would like to display the Bar that matches that BarIdentifier

**Update with example**

As requested I tried to do a short example. Included a function GetCalcDataForCondition how to filter out the CalcData based on selected Condition.

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace FilterSample
{
    public class CalcData
    {
        public Condition Condition { get; set; }
        public int Diameter { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class Condition
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class BaseClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class TagClass : BaseClass
    {
    }

    class ConnectionClass : BaseClass
    {
        public List<CalcData> CalcData { get; set; }
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        public int PosX { get; set; }
        public int PosY { get; set; }

        public BaseClass Content { get; set; }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public List<Condition> Conditions { get; set; }
        public List<Holder> Holders { get; set; }

        public int SelectedConditionId { get; set; }

        private void GenerateData()
        {
            Conditions = new List<Condition>();
            Conditions.Add(new Condition() { Id = 1, Name = "Condition 1" });
            Conditions.Add(new Condition() { Id = 2, Name = "Condition 2" });
            Conditions.Add(new Condition() { Id = 3, Name = "Condition 3" });
            Conditions.Add(new Condition() { Id = 4, Name = "Condition 4" });
            Conditions.Add(new Condition() { Id = 5, Name = "Condition 5" });

            Holders = new List<Holder>();
            Holders.Add(new Holder() { PosX = 10, PosY = 10, Content = new TagClass() { } });
            Holders.Add(new Holder() { PosX = 10, PosY = 110, Content = GenerateConnectionClass(1, Conditions) });
            Holders.Add(new Holder() { PosX = 10, PosY = 210, Content = new TagClass() { } });
            Holders.Add(new Holder() { PosX = 10, PosY = 310, Content = GenerateConnectionClass(2, Conditions) });
            Holders.Add(new Holder() { PosX = 10, PosY = 410, Content = new TagClass() { } });
        }

        private ConnectionClass GenerateConnectionClass(int index, List<Condition> conditions)
        {
            var conn = new ConnectionClass();

            conn.Name = "Connection " + index;
            conn.CalcData = new List<CalcData>();
            foreach (var c in conditions)
            {
                conn.CalcData.Add(new CalcData() { Condition = c, Name = "Calc values for condition " + c.Id, Diameter = c.Id * 100 });
            }

            return conn;
        }

        private CalcData GetCalcDataForCondition(ConnectionClass conn, Condition condition)
        {
            return conn.CalcData.First(c => c.Condition.Id == condition.Id);
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            GenerateData();
            SelectedConditionId = 1;
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="FilterSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FilterSample"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TagClass }" >
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <Label Content="Tag Class" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ConnectionClass }">
            <Border CornerRadius="4" Background="White" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource NormalBorderBrush}" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Label Content="Connection Class" />

                    <Label Content="HERE I WANT TO DISPLAY related CalcData.Name" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Holder }">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  >
                <Label Content="This is Holder Class" FontWeight="Bold" />
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=Content}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Select condition " Height="24" />
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Conditions}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedConditionId}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id" Width="200" Height="24" />

        </StackPanel>

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Holders}" Grid.Row="1">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=PosX , Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=PosY, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Since `Foo2` is not containing any information about selected bar, an answer will depend on the context of usage. By the way: is the `BarList` in `Foo2` related to the selection of bars or is it something completely different?

Comment: BarList in Foo2 hold a List of Bar classes. That list is what I want to filter out based on the BarIdentifier selected in the ViewModel. I see if I can create a MCVE and update.

Comment: Made an update with an example

Comment: I was a bit confused by your MCVE, because there is `"Calc values for condition 1"`, no matter which condition was selected. I suggest to change it: `"new CalcData() { Condition = c, Name = "Calc values for condition " + c.Id, Diameter = c.Id * 100 }"` otherwise you may have a working example that appears like its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need *some* way to transfer your selected condition Id to the inner data templates. My suggestion: Make the `DataTemplate` for `Holder` depend on the selected condition (move it from resources into the content as `<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>`) and create a `UserControl` for `Holder`. Add a `SelectedConditionId` to the usercontrol and assign it:

```
<Window
        ...>

    <Grid x:Name="grid1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Select condition " Height="24" />
            <ComboBox x:Name="condSelector" ItemsSource="{Binding Conditions}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedConditionId}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id" Width="200" Height="24" />
        </StackPanel>

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Holders}" Grid.Row="1">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=PosX , Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=PosY, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <!-- Here it is -->
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:HolderControl DataContext="{Binding}" SelectedConditionId="{Binding ElementName=condSelector,Path=SelectedValue}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Move most of your things into the holder control and use its `SelectedConditionId` with a `MultiBinding` to get the selected `CalcData`:

```
<UserControl
        ....
        x:Name="uc1">
    <UserControl.Resources>

        <local:SelectedCalcDataConverter x:Key="calcDataSelector"/>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TagClass }" >
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <Label Content="Tag Class" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ConnectionClass }">
            <Border CornerRadius="4" Background="White" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource NormalBorderBrush}" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackPanel.DataContext>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource calcDataSelector}" Mode="OneWay">
                            <Binding Path="CalcData"/>
                            <Binding ElementName="uc1" Path="SelectedConditionId"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </StackPanel.DataContext>
                    <Label Content="Connection Class" />

                    <!--Label Content="HERE I WANT TO DISPLAY related CalcData.Name" /-->
                    <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  >
            <Label Content="This is Holder Class" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=Content}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class HolderControl : UserControl
{
    public HolderControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public int? SelectedConditionId
    {
        get { return (int?)GetValue(SelectedConditionIdProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedConditionIdProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedConditionId.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedConditionIdProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedConditionId", typeof(int?), typeof(HolderControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());
}
```

And the converter:

```
public class SelectedCalcDataConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var items = values[0] as IEnumerable<CalcData>;
        var selectedId = values[1] as int?;

        if (items != null)
        {
            var result = items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Condition.Id == selectedId);
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

There are other approaches to transport the selected ID around, but this one is relatively easy to understand.

Comment: Awsome! Worked, had to change the Bindings on a couple of things, since I'm using Caliburn Micro as MVVM and want to reference ViewModel. But this got me to a working solution, awsome! Thank you